# Question about a proof of Fitting lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, operator-theory

I read a proof from @chess64 's [AoPS blog](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c994h994166):

> If $T$ is a linear operator on $V$ and $n = \dim V$, $ V = \text{null } T^n \oplus \text{range } T^n$.
>
> Proof:
> Any $v$ in $V$ can be written $ v = T^n(v) + (v - T^n(v))$, where $ T^n(v) \in \text{range }T^n$ and $ T^n(v-T^n(v)) = T^n(v) - T^{2n}(v) = 0$ (follows from [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c994h994165) and the fact that $n =\dim V$). Therefore we have $ V = \text{null } T^n + \text{range } T^n$.
>
> Now suppose $ v \in \text{null } T^n$ and $ v \in \text{range } T^n$. There is a $ v'$ such that $ T^n(v') = v$, so $ T^{2n}(v') = 0$ (since $ T^n(v) = 0$. This means $ v' \in \text{null } T^{2n} = \text{null } T^n$ so $ T^n(v') = 0$. But we defined $ T^n(v') = v$, so $ v = 0$. Thus $ \text{null }T^n \cap \text{range } T^n = \{0\}$, so we have a direct sum.

In the first part of the proof, $T^n(v) - T^{2n}(v) = 0$, why is this?

I know that $T^n(V) - T^{2n}(V) = 0$ (since the descending chain $V\supseteq T(V)\supseteq T^2(V)\supseteq\dots$ stabilize in at most $n$ steps) but I think this doesn't imply $T^n(v) - T^{2n}(v) = 0$ for any $v$ in $V$.

Comment: I edited your title.  The term "doubt" outside of Indian English *never* means you have a question about something.  It means you're suspicious about it or think it might be wrong, so you'd sound like a crank if you said you have "a doubt about the Pythagorean theorem", for example.

Comment: Yes I think the proof from the blog might be wrong.

Comment: I still think "doubt" is not the right term to use.  Maybe "Possible error" or "Gap" would work better.

Comment: By the way, the link http://www.mathlinks.ro/weblog_entry.php?t=276415 in the original blog post has expired , so I used the new link https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c994h994165 instead.

Comment: I think  you are correct.

Comment: Can you give an counterexample?